# I need to handle Serial UART (pins 8,10) for raspberry pi3, OS Windows 10 IoT

Tags: windowsiot

I nead to know the name of the COM port for UART0 (pins 8,10) on the raspberry pi 3.
I should run a c++ server (library for our control system is c++). So I need the device name for following
CreateFile("\\.\COMx",...); (or the name in other form)
In the case of rasperrian jessie OS I know how to enable it and what is the device name after enabling (http://spellfoundry.com/2016/05/29/configuring-gpio-serial-port-raspbian-jessie-including-pi-3/).
We would like to try also Windows 10 IoT for some of our raspberrians.
Any comments is apreciated.
Davit

Comment: C:\Data\Users\doocsadm>devcon /hwids =Ports
ACPI\BCM2836\0
    Name: BCM283x Mini UART Serial Device
    Hardware IDs:
        ACPI\VEN_BCM&DEV_2836
        ACPI\BCM2836
        *BCM2836
    Compatible IDs:
        ACPI\MINIUART
        MINIUART
1 matching device(s) found.
                                                                                                                                                             
C:\Data\Users\doocsadm>

My expectation is to see here the name of serial port, am I right?

Answer (score 2):

> > So I need the device name for following CreateFile("\.\COMx",...); (or the name in other form)

Windows 10 IoT Core can also use CreateFile function in Windows IoT Core Console  C++ project.

1. You can get the device name from the project SerialUART. 
   [image]
2. Then you can follow this instruction to try to get the device name like L"\\?\ACPI#BCM2836#0#{86e0d1e0-8089-11d0-9ce4-08003e301f73}". 
   [image]
3. At last you can create a windows iot core C++ project and use CreateFile("\\?\ACPI...",...); for getting file handle.
   [image]

Link:

https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/SerialUART

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/serialuart

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint.
I think this is right way for reaching the goal.
Now I have another problem
Error: Failed to open handle to serial device. (DevicePath = \\?\ACPI#BCM2836#0#{86e0d1e0-8089-11d0-9ce4-08003e301f73}, GetLastError() = 0x5)
Error code number 5 is 'Access denied'
I tried to enable access following this article 'https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/Samples/CustomDeviceAccessor', but up to now not sucessfull :)

Comment: You could try to create a C++ console app for using CreateFile(). I have accessed serial port on RP3 successfully by using power shell for running .exe on RP3.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I found the soultion also here (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0ffbd1c4-d61c-4958-b71f-40b70bbec535/windows-10-iot-serial-uart-pins-810-for-rasp-pi3?forum=WindowsIoT)